# Replacing character after certain character length

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to do a function to replace all the character after a certain length of character to asterisk, and so far what i did is like this.

```
var text = 'ABCDEFG';
var newText = text.substring(0,3) + text.substring(3).replace(/\S/g,'*');
```

If would give me what I need, but it is fairly inefficient as I understand it, and i trying to change it to make it more efficient.

```
text.replace(/.{4}$/,'*');
```

Unfortunately the result is not i expected and also it need to be hardcode the length of 4 counting from behind, which it wont work if the word's length is different.

Is there any regex method that able to replace all other character to asterisk after certain length of character (in this case is 3).

Any help to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edited:
**As conclusion of the suggestion and discussion**

Alternative way to solve the problem, which giving the almost identical result as my solution.

```
text.replace(/(\w{3}).*/g, "$1"+(new Array(text.length -3 + 1).join( '*' )));
```

by @Keerthana Prabhakaran

```
text.replace(new RegExp(".(?=.{0," + (text.length-4) + "}$)", "g"), '*')
```

by @Wiktor Stribiżew

```
var longerThanNeeded = "***************************";
var newText = text.substring(0,3) + longerThanNeeded.substring(0,text.length-3);
```

by @matthewninja

```
(^.{3}).|. and replace w/ \1*
```

by @alpha bravo

As discuss with some of the people, due to the efficiency of the code are almost the same even for the original code that I make of. Therefore it stated as side discussing.

Appreciated the helps once again.

Comment: Why is your code inefficient?

Comment: It took 2 action to did what i need, which i hope it done in 1. although is not really a must, just hope it can be done in more compact way

Comment: That's incorrect. Even  if a regex did what you want, it would internally be doing similar sets of operations (or more). Just because your code is larger, doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: `text.replace(/(\w{3}).*/g, "$1"+(new Array(text.length -3 + 1).join( '*' )));` would help! Javascript strings are immutable and hence, the ways you've tried is also actually efficient. To make the code generic, assign 3 to a variable and use that everywhere in the code so that you need to change only in one place if the length varies!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran That isn't more efficient than OP's solution. .join() needs to run for every element of the array with '*', so time complexity grows linearly, same as OP.

Comment: I didnt mention its more efficient! Its just another way of solving the problem. That is why I added as a comment instead of an answer!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Fair enough. Your solution certainly is eloquent.

Comment: I think `s.replace(new RegExp(".(?=.{0," + (s.length-4) + "}$)", "g"), '*')` will work when you need to replace each but the first char. Replace `.` with `[\s\S]` to support newline matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution work great on the situation. Appreciate that!

Comment: @Dean There is one catch: it is still better to check if the string length is more than the length of the regex pattern.

Comment: Agree with that, same problem with @alpha bravo's solution. still appreciate the help for all of you guys.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I'm not overthinking this.

`text.substring(3).replace(/\S/g,'*');` has linear time complexity `O(n)` and isn't terribly inefficient.

I initially thought of using `Array.prototype.join()` like so:

`var newText = text.substring(0,3) + Array(text.length-2).join("*");`

Before realizing that .join() needs to run for every element of the array, which results in linear time complexity, just like your original solution. This wouldn't improve the solution at all; All I've done is inflate the space complexity.

I then went on to think of creating the element to be joined by copying and increasing the size of the prior element, which would get us down to `0(log n)` complexity.

Finally, I saw the most obvious solution.

```
var longerThanNeeded = "***************************";
var newText = text.substring(0,3) + longerThanNeeded.substring(0,text.length-3);
```

which will run in constant time.

Comment: this could be an alternative way to do it, but it is bad having a hardcode for the variable `longerThanNeeded`, but other than that, is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this pattern `(^.{3}).|.` and replace w/ `\1*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v1ggVQ/1/)

(Please note limitation for strings less than 3 characters in length)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  ^             # Start of string/line
  .             # Any character except line break
  {3}           # (repeated {3} times)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
.               # Any character except line break
|               # OR
.               # Any character except line break
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but there is an problem here... if the words is lesser than 3 character it will mask away all of it, this is my fault for did't mention if it is lesser than 3 character it wont replace with asterisk

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s.replace(new RegExp(".(?=.{0," + (s.length-4) + "}$)", "g"), '*')
```

See a JS demo:

```js
var text = 'ABCDEFG';
var threshold = 3; // Start replacing with * after this value
if (text.length > threshold) {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(".(?=.{0," + (text.length-threshold-1) + "}$)", "g"), '*');
}
console.log(text);
```

Here, if `threshold` is `3`, the pattern will look like `.(?=.{0,3}$)`: it matches any char but a line break char with `.` that is followed with 0 to 3 chars other than line break chars (`.{0,3}`) and the end of string position (`$`). The `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that only checks for the pattern match, but does not move the regex index and does not add the matched text to the match value (allowing subsequent consecutive symbol check).

To enable matching line breaks, replace `.` with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.